# C# Create table from DataContext Table?

Tags: c#

Is there a built in way to create a table if it does not exist from the DataContext Table class? Or is the only way to use raw sql statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about using the built in linq-to-sql datacontext class then you can always refresh it from the database if you create a new table and it should be picked up.

How about defining the table manually like this:

```
[Table(Name = "mydb.dbo.myTable")]
public class MyTable 
{
    [Column(Name = "Id", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "ActiveDate")]
    public DateTime? ActiveDate { get; set; }

}
```

then you can access the table like this:

```
var table =  _seatingDataContext.Context.GetTable<MyTable>();
```

Then you can query it or add rows or whatever.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, so the Refresh method will create the tables?

Comment: Well it's probably easier to create the table in the database and then regenerate the database context, after which time the datacontext will contain your new table.

Comment: Is it possible to create the context from a database layout? I am trying with sqlce 3.5 and I keep getting not supported errors. I really don't want to have to maintain create tables queries alone with contexts.

Comment: Sorry you didnt state you were using SQL Compact Edition in your original question, I'm not sure of the compatibility between that and linq-to-sql contexts

Comment: Ya I am now learning that. Does SQL Server support embedding?

Comment: Whay if you really want to create tables from c#? Think of the case of a new install.